# RHEL5 + Awesome WM - How do i fix mod4 inversion (acts like mod4 is always pressed)

Tags: linux, rhel-5

I built and installed Awesome WM on RHEL5. I have  problem with mod4 acting like its always pressed. ie every time i hit "Enter" it acts like Mod4+Enter was hit. I have to hold down mod4 key (I remapped it to Caps_Lock) to actually send through just a Enter.

How do i fix this?

PS: If i change the WM this problem doesnt exist.

---

yes. I do. It is mostly tab configs though. I didnt change key combos.

Also, the version of awesomeWM i compiled is 3.1.1 (had trouble getting deps for the latest AwesomeWM on Rhel5)

Comment: Do you have a custom rc ?

Comment: Any more suggestions on what i should be looking into?

Answer (score 1):

This inversion has just happened to me, but I found no answers on the internet. It ended up resulting that I had vim-eaten the line in my custom rc.lua where it stated `modkey = "Mod4"` and not noticed it. Once I restored this line my awesome is doing awesome again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something as following?

```
setxkbmap gb -options:caps-escape
```

This way your Caps-Lock will change behaviour to being a simple Mod4 button. You can also remap Caps-lock to Mod4 via xmodmap, but beware that setxkbmap and xmodmap are not good friends.

Although this does not answer the question directly, I hope it will be of some to you...